# How to update OpenShift Cartridge with oo-admin-upgrade?

Tags: openshift-origin

I have an application running in OpenShift Origin. It has been running for some time and now I have an update for the cartridge it uses.

When I try to update cartridge, script fails.

```
[root@broker ~]# oo-admin-upgrade --upgrade-node node1 --login admin --app-name app1 --version 1.0 --upgrade-gear 52231466a6577a242f00015d
/usr/sbin/oo-admin-upgrade:76:in `rescue in upgrade_gear': Can only supply discovery data if direct_addressing is enabled (RuntimeError)
["/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/mcollective/rpc/client.rb:438:in `discover'", "/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-msg-broker-mcollective-1.13.0.1/lib/openshift/mcollective_application_container_proxy.rb:2173:in `rpc_exec'", "/usr/sbin/oo-admin-upgrade:49:in `block in upgrade_gear'", "/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/timeout.rb:69:in `timeout'", "/usr/sbin/oo-admin-upgrade:41:in `upgrade_gear'", "/usr/sbin/oo-admin-upgrade:611:in `<main>'"]
Output:
Migrating gear on node with: /usr/sbin/oo-admin-upgrade --login 'admin' --upgrade-gear '52231466a6577a242f00015d' --app-name 'app1' --version '1.0' 
Upgrading on node...
    from /usr/sbin/oo-admin-upgrade:24:in `upgrade_gear'
    from /usr/sbin/oo-admin-upgrade:611:in `<main>'
```

Do I do something wrong or it is a bug in the script?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're probably one of the first people attempting to use `oo-admin-upgrade` in their origin installation.  This looks like the mcollective command to the node to upgrade the gear timed out.  Please make sure mcollective is correctly configured by running 'mco ping' - you should see responses from all nodes in your cluster.

That said, the `upgrade-node` option is not designed to be used by end-users.  Please use:

```
oo-admin-upgrade --version 1.0
```

This should apply upgrades for all apps in your cluster.